# Como convertir un entero en un constexpr

Tags: c++, template

Estoy haciendo un programa en c++ con plantillas y necesito especificarle un entero de forma :

```
string cadena="00110101011";
int a =cadena.lenght();
bitset <a> b1 (cadena);
```

Pero el compilador dice que "a" no es una expresion constante o constexpr, por lo que me pregunto como puedo hacer para que reconozca el valor ?

He probado haciendo :

```
constexpr int a= cadena.length();
```

Pero el error luego cae sobre el metodo length.

Answer (score 4):

`constexpr` solo puede usarse con elementos cuyo valor pueda evaluarse en tiempo de compilación, entre otros tantos requisitos. Para cumplir este requisito es imprescindible que el objeto **no use memoria dinámica**, y lamento comunicarte que `std::string` **sí usa** memoria dinámica.

Una posible alternativa:

```
char constexpr cadena[]="00110101011";
int constexpr a = sizeof(cadena);
std::bitset<a> b1 (cadena);
```

Ahora bien, nota que como `constexpr` se evalúa en tiempo de compilación, no será posible usarlo con variables o con funciones que **no sean** `constexpr`, es decir, no será posible usarlo con elementos que interactúen con el usuario, que lean de ficheros, ...

```
char constexpr *cadena= funcionQueNecesito(); // <<--- ERROR de compilación
int constexpr a = sizeof(cadena);
std::bitset<a> b1 (cadena);
```

Answer (score 4):

Para que algo sea una `constexpr`, debes declararlo como `constexpr`:

```
constexpr std::string cadena = "00110101011";
constexpr int a = cadena.length();
std::bitset<a> b1(cadena)
```

Pero esto no compila, porque no sabes ni qué son las expresiones constantes (`constexpr`) ni por qué te la está pidiendo.

---

#### Plantilla `std::bitset`.

La plantilla [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) está declarada en la cabecera homónima ([`<bitset>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bitset)) y su definición es la siguiente:

```
template< std::size_t N >
class bitset;
```

Es decir, es una plantilla con un único parámetro no-tipo que se corresponde con el tamaño que deberá tener la colección de bits.

Los parámetros de las plantillas deben ser conocidos en tiempo de compilación. Los tipos de valores que son conocidos en tiempo de compilación son:

- Literales (por ejemplo `1`, `101010b`, `.42f`, `"Mi mama me mima"`).
- Expresiones constantes (por ejemplo `1 + 2`, `constexpr auto a = funcion_constexpr()`).

#### Plantilla `std::string`.

La plantilla [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), para ser usada como una expresión constante, deberá tener funciones marcadas como `constexpr`, en tu caso necesitas tanto el constructor como la función `length`, pero no es el caso:

- Ninguno de los [constructores de `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) es `constexpr`.
- La función [`length`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) no es `constexpr`.

---

#### Propuesta.

Utiliza un literal de cadena de texto:

```
constexpr auto cadena = "00110101011";
std::bitset<std::extent_v<decltype(cadena)>> b1(cadena);
```

Al definirlo como `auto`, el compilador calculará el tamaño necesario. Para inferir el tamaño necesario usa [`std::extent`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) que como podemos ver en su definición, **si** es `constexpr`:

```
template< class T, unsigned N = 0 >
inline constexpr std::size_t extent_v = extent<T, N>::value;
```

Comment: +1, pero reconoce que usar `char[]` es bastante menos doloroso para la vista ;-p

Comment: @Trauma no lo reconoceré, porque sobre gustos no hay nada escrito.